# Missing lib.exe while compiling Notepad++ dll in C#

Tags: c#, dll, notepad++

I want to compile a plugin for Notepad++ and used a [.NET plugin](https://notepad-plus-plus.org/contribute/plugin-howto.html/) to be able to write it in C# (VS17).
Without adding any code myself, the warning "Cannot find lib.exe in [...]\VC\bin" pops up.
I do get the .dll file but Npp throws two errors when adding the plugin to it:

1. Wrong version of Plugin
2. ANSI/Unicode Error

I am pretty sure that at least the version is correct, as I tried it with multiple Npp-versions, so i figured that maybe it's all about that warning.
Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

"lib.exe" is part of the C/C++ toolset and is installed when support for the C/C++ language is selected in Visual Studio. Modify your Visual Studio to include C/C++ support. Running the set up program should allow the wanted suport to be selected and installed.